# hiding href path as a layer of security

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'd like to hide the HREF path so that it does not appear when the page is saved, and also to hide it from the dev tools inspector . I tried echoing the href path using php; however this doesn't hide it when the page is being inspected using dev tools. is there any possible way to do it?

i am trying to do this as a layer of security which might prevent malicious  users to know the path to my folders, and also making some kind of confusion to how I write my paths.

many thanks.

Comment: As I know, you can't. You can replace the href to a javascript function `location.href` but the user could see it if he will look in the js files (You can always minified it).

Comment: Try and turn this around, malicious users hiding the href's and suddenly you are on a malicious site.

Comment: I don't know PHP, but doesn't it let you do some kind of URL routing (like Java, .net, etc. do)? The URLs the user sees in the browser shouldn't need to relate directly to your real folder structure.

Comment: Don't do this! Protect your backend/folder instead from malicious user. They can always find a way to get the folder's path. Easiest is just by looking in the network tab to see what requests are being made

Comment: You should maybe considering creating uniq temporary short links instead of trying to hide them

Comment: Your SEO ranking will be hurt by doing this

Comment: Thanks guys for your contributions. nnnnnn yes it is possible to do URL routing using PHP, but I don't Know whether this is the best way to protect my folders path?